# How to redirect user after to another page using PayPal smart buttons

Tags: javascript, java, html, paypal

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
        location.href="mywebsite";
      });
    },
```

I have been trying to find out how to do this for awhile, I have tried "location.replace()" as well, but it still didn't work. I want to redirect a user after payment is accepted. The alert feature does work, but only in sandboxes, when I try and use it on my real site the alert, and the redirect does not work. I am using Google Sites, could that be an issue? This is just the basic code that you get when you create a PayPal smart button, all I added was "location.href", but it won't redirect me. I will try my best to answer any questions! Any help on this matter is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproduced code example?

Answer (score 0):

Within your `.then()` function, use `actions.redirect()` or set `window.location.href`

Comment: I apologies, but what do you mean by that? Can you send an example?

Comment: I tried the window.location.href, it still did not work. My new code is:                                    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            window.location.href="https://www.ntcclan.org/player-id-314lh1324hqwe9ruadfpo3248apwd8f433eudfqe-successful";
          });
        },

Comment: A URL requires a protocol

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong with it! It was trying to turn the PayPal window into the website, but the window would shut down before I could catch the error!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but this is what worked for me:

```
window.location.replace('https://website.com');
```

Answer (score -1):

Setting Up Auto Return Using PayPal

To set up Auto Return:

Log in to paypal and click Profile.
Click the Website Payment Preferences link under Selling Preferences.
Click the On radio button to enable Auto Return. Enter the Return URL.
Note: You must meet the Return URL requirements in order to set up Auto Return. Learn more about Return URL.

Sendbox Form Multiple Return Request URL's : If you are using different URL's for success/failure

It will automatically overwrite paypal specified URL.

Comment: This will not work with the new Subscription Button. Also, only good it you only have one website that uses Paypal.